# Bring all rows to one row

Tags: regex, excel

In Excel, I have rows like below:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
9 8 7 6 5
...
```

I need to bring all of them to the first row:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 ...
```

The numbers of rows and columns are fixed.

What is the fastest way I can achieve this?

Alternatively, can I solve this on a Textpad or Notepad++ using some REGEX grouping?

Comment: Are the numbers really sequenced like that?  I.e., do you just need that pattern across the top row?  Also, if rows/columns and fixed, what's the count of each?

Comment: No, what I have put in is some mock data. No. of columns 5 and no. of rows 10

Comment: How many rows do you have that you need to do this for? If not many, then it's probably faster to just do it by hand. There's not one simple formula or operation that will move them for you. One thing you could try, though, is export the table as a CSV, then in a text editor, join all the lines as one line (eliminate the line breaks), then re-import the CSV.

Comment: yes that worked.. i did a simple replace for \r\n with " "

Comment: Pls mention as answer and i shall mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it with an Excel formula, pasting the following, starting in column F, would produce it across the top row:

```
=INDIRECT("r"&CEILING(COLUMN()/5,1)&"c"&IF(MOD(COLUMN(),5)=0,5,MOD(COLUMN(),5)),FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table started from A2 and your row values are to be copied from A1 onwards, following should work:

```
=OFFSET($A$2, (COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$1))/5, MOD(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$1), 5))
```

However, I think for just a small table of size 5X10, using '=' sign manually would be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I just select and drag them up there.  When there was a pattern of projects I wrote a VBA function to do the job, but for most small unique projects select and drag worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, for Find what : `\r\n`, Replace with : `'space'` with Search Mode Extended, Replace All, then copy result into Excel.

With images :)  here:

[Replace Carriage Return and Line Feed in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/545461/replace-carriage-return-and-line-feed-in-notepad).